# If a cell contains a specific text, then other cells cannot be blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel sheet that used by multiple analysts (individual copies) however I want to force them to enter data in certain cells if a desired cell has a data.

For example, if cell A1 contains "Hello", Excel should force uses to enter in a range B1 to F1 and so on. This should be applicable for 5000+ rows in the same sheet.

A pop up message would be good so that they know what they must do.

I have tried VBA solutions on stackoverflow but it did not work for me.

Comment: As one option you could use the Worksheet SelectionChange event, and in that code, check the value of cell `A1`, and if the `Target` of the event is outside of your B1 or F1 or whatever you are forcing them to, you select a cell inside of that range, forcing them back into it. Good luck!

Comment: Is there a way to display a message e.g. "Cells B1 to F1 cannot be blank" when they write `Hello` in A1. This will be better than just targeting to those cells.

Comment: Yeah. Just throw a `msgbox("Cells B1 to F1 cannot be blank")` in that code.

Answer (score 0):

What about conditional formatting, based on this formula: `=NOT(LEN($A1)=0)`?

The results look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Dominique, I am looking for a VBA solution as I cannot write any formulas in the blank cells. Users must enter something in B1 to F1, depending upon what they have written in A1

Comment: @meonxl5321: You seem not to understand what I mean: one can create a conditional formatting rule, based on a formula. In order to see if this works, just enter the formula inside the corresponding cell and check if the result is `TRUE` or not.
If so, the formula can be used as a basis for conditional formatting, and the formula can be erased from the cell content.